# check if a non linear system of equations of $n$ unknowns has a solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am new in working with system of equations. I know that:  for linear systems of equations, one can check if the  equations are linearly independent  to  prove if the system has a solution or not.

What methods can be used to prove that a system of non linear equations (indeed algebraic equations) has a solution ?

Does the number of equations hsould be also $n$ ( as the number of unknowns is $n$) ?

Any reference in this manner would be great.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, nice question! I am wondering if you ever found an answer to it?